# New Mac clean install except for Music?

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, install, apple-music

I'm getting a new MacBook, and I would like to do a clean install of everything **except** Apple Music where I would like to copy exactly my current set up (all songs, rating, play count, playlist, etc). Is that doable?

Comment: what do you use to play music